# php includes chain

Tags: php, architecture, include, chaining

Here is my problem, I ve got an old website which contains some modules like this,

```
root_dir
    |-->module1
    |-->module2
    |-->module3
```

For my need I add a sublevel to this structure, like this,

```
root_dir
    |-->module1
    |-->module2
        |-->submodule2.1
    |-->module3
```

My problem is that each module include an "include.php" file which then include other files, so if I fix the first path of the include.php to ../include.php it will crash at the second include file...

Is there a good workaround here, besides duplicating all the files and fix the path of the include ?

Thx

Comment: Just to get the question: module2 includes an include.php, which in turn includes submodule2.1, which then includes an includes.php inside the folder of the submodule2.1; so, what do you want to include there, if that is the end of the chain, and everything else might be included earlier?

Comment: actually it's more like submodule2.1 and module2 are not linked at all, there both standalone but they include the same include.php (which load the config environnment of the site), in module2 it works perfectly cause it has been made for this, so there something like this <?php include("../include/include.php"); ?> and for the submodule2.1 I need to adapt the path to this, <?php include("../../include/include.php"); ?> but then I ve got error with the included files embbed in the include.php ...(hard to explain ouch, hope you understand me )

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) for your common include.php file:

```
include_once('../include.php');
```

Or including the code once in a common ancestor file.

Or am I over simplifying? Are these options to you?

Comment: I think it s not gonna works cause all modules are standalone, there is no ancestor (old website) basically I want to include the start of the included chain but from different folder hierarchy, it works for the first one cause i modify the path but then it creates errors...There's probalby something with dirname_FILE_ but I just ask before I miss something ...

Comment: @krifur: Using `dirname(__FILE__);` througout your whole code (or `__DIR__` in more recent versions) sounds about right. Never assume a working dir. Although you can of course call `chdir` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

"there both standalone but they include the same include.php (which load the config environnment of the site)"

You better should have the configuration loaded already or work with some method (a factory to get configuration-data from, a global settings-class, …) that allows to load settings, without knowing anything about your actual file-structure (from a modules point of view). The same holds true for everything else you are using within the modules (like a database object).